# Java to C++ conversion

Tags: java, c++, queue

I am trying to convert some java code to c++, however, I am having an issue with java's list.add versus c++ list.insert. Here is the java code that I've started to convert:

```
public class SimulationQueue {
    private String arrivalFilePath;
    private int currentTime;

    private class Event {
        private boolean arrival;
        private int start;
        private int span;

        public Event() {
            this.arrival = true;
            this.start = 0;
            this.span = 0;
        }

        public Event(boolean isArrival, int startTime, int span) {
            this.arrival = isArrival;
            this.start = startTime;
            this.span = span;
        }

        public int at() { return start; }
        public boolean isArrival() { return arrival; }
        public int duration() { return span; }

        public void getArrivalEvent(Scanner arrivalFile) {
            this.arrival = true;
            this.start = arrivalFile.nextInt();
            this.span = arrivalFile.nextInt();
        }
    }

    public SimulationQueue(String arrivalFilePath) {
        this.arrivalFilePath = arrivalFilePath;
        this.currentTime = 0;
    }

    private void addEventToList(Event event, List<Event> eventList) {
        if (eventList.isEmpty()) eventList.add(0, event);
        else if (eventList.get(0).at() < event.at()) eventList.add(event);
        else eventList.add(0, event);
    }
```

And here is the so far converted c++ version:

```
struct EventList {
    bool arrival;
    int start, span, currentTime;
    string arrivalFilePath;
    EventList(bool isArrival, int startTime, int span);
    void getArrivalEvent(istream& arrivalFile);
    void simulationQueue (string arrivalFilePath);
    void addEventToList(EventList& event, list<EventList> eventList);
    void simulate();

    EventList() {
    this->arrival = true;
    this->start = 0;
    this->span = 0;
    }

    int at() {
        return start;
    }

    bool isArrival() {
        return arrival;
    }

    int duration() {
        return span;
    }
};

EventList::EventList(bool isArrival, int startTime, int span) {
    this->arrival = isArrival;
    this->start = startTime;
    this->span = span;
}

void EventList::getArrivalEvent(istream& arrivalFile) {
    this->arrival = true;
    int first = this->start;
    int duration = this->span;
    arrivalFile >> first;
    arrivalFile >> duration;
}

void EventList::simulationQueue (string arrivalFilePath) {
    this->arrivalFilePath = arrivalFilePath;
    this->currentTime = 0;
}

void EventList::addEventToList(EventList& event, list<EventList> eventList) {
    if (eventList.empty())
}
```

I'm not very experienced so I know I'm probably approaching this wrong but it's compiling alright. The issue I have is with:

```
void EventList::addEventToList(EventList& event, list<EventList> eventList) {
        if (eventList.empty())
    }
```

I don't know how to convert this part to c++:

```
private void addEventToList(Event event, List<Event> eventList) {
            if (eventList.isEmpty()) eventList.add(0, event);
            else if (eventList.get(0).at() < event.at()) eventList.add(event);
            else eventList.add(0, event);
        }
```

If I write something like `event.insert(event, 0)` then it won't fit the parameters that insert takes.

Comment: BTW, if you use `struct`, the default access modifier is going to be `public`. What's wrong with `class`?

Comment: well, for one, you're passing a copy of ``eventList`` rather than a reference, so your modifications to it aren't going to persist outside the function call... And does ``EventList`` define a sensical copy-constructor? Because otherwise inserting it into a list isn't going to do what you expect either... Basically, I highly recommend you read up some more C++ tutorials before attempting this, C++ is not a language you just go into thinking you can write code that looks similar to Java and have it work correctly.

Comment: @awesomeyi Many people (including myself) don't subscribe to strict information hiding paradigms and prefer most if not all of a class' implementation to be `public`.

Comment: @aruisdante - I agree with you.  But to give Giovanni some credit, at least it doesn't use `new` all over the place without calling `delete`.  The code looks like some attempt to read up on C++ was done.  Usually, a Java-to-C++ translation looks worse than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `list::push_back`.

```
void EventList::addEventToList(EventList& event, list<EventList> eventList) {
    eventList.push_back(event);
}
```

However, if you leave it just like that, the calling function won't see the new item in the list since you passed `eventList` to the function by value. You need to pass it by reference.

```
void EventList::addEventToList(EventList& event, list<EventList>& eventList) {
    eventList.push_back(event);
}
```

`list::push_back` adds items to the end (back) of the list. If you'd rather add the item at the start (front) of the list, you can use `list::push_front`.

```
void EventList::addEventToList(EventList& event, list<EventList>& eventList) {
    eventList.push_front(event);
}
```